# How do you interpret jQuery(document).ready()?

Tags: jquery

So `jQuery()` is is a function and document is an object which is used as a parameter of the `jQuery()` function.

I suppose, the `jQuery(document)` function then return an object, which has a ready() method? Is it correct? What kind of object does `jQuery(document)` return then?

Comment: `jQuery(document)` returns a jQuery object, containing the `document` DOM element. It is the same as every other `$(x)` selector, which returns DOM element(s), wrapped in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses a lot of magic (e.g. to avoid the need of using `new`).

`jQuery(...)` always creates a new jQuery object, containing zero or more elements (depending on the arguments) passed to it.

jQuery has a `ready` method so you can call it on any jQuery object. It doesn't matter if you use `$().ready()` or `$(document).ready()` or `$('whatever').ready()` - it will always do the same thing:

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // Add the callback
    readyList.add( fn );

    return this;
},
```

As you can see, `this` is only returned for chaining - the actual logic of the function does not use it at all.

Comment: I suppose JavaScript is an object-oriented language with the concept of classes(types)? And so there is a class called jQuery? And which class does the jQuery function belong to?

Comment: JavaScript does not have classes, it has objects. This is outside the scope of a comment though - but there are lots of high-voted (=> good) questions/answers about this here on SO. But here's a short answer anyway: `jQuery()` is a *constructor function* which contains magic to work properly even without `new`.

Comment: ThiefMaster's comment is perfectly accurate, though potentially misleading if you're new to the spectrum of languages with some form of OO support.  Javascript can be used in an OO fashion.  The word "class" is the part that doesn't make much sense in Javascript.  I also agree that the subject is out of scope for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of object does `jQuery(document)` return then?

It returns a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery):

> A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a document.

The `jQuery` method itself is documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

> The second and third formulations of this function create a jQuery object using one or more DOM elements that were already selected in some other way. A common use of this facility is to call jQuery methods on an element that has been passed to a callback function ...

The `jQuery(...)` function is also commonly abbreviated `$(...)`, as in:

```
$(document)
```

Basically it is the first common hook into the jQuery library.  You'll quite often see it used this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This code gets called once the document has finished loading
  // to the point where you'd want to use the jQuery library against the DOM
});
```

Here is documentation on the `.ready` method:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code ...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ - you're interested in the `jQuery( element )` version of the `jQuery` function. It wraps the element you pass in a new `jQuery` object. This object then contains a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method where you can pass an event handler as a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you take typeof document, you will get object so jQuery(document) will give the jQuery object of document.

You might have done like $(this) to treat this as jQuery object. With javascript keyword this we can call all the dom method/properties but not jQuery methods and properties similarly with $(this) we can call all jquery methods / properties but not basic dom methods and properties.

Now $(document).ready() means to get the dom object document convert it to jQuery object and attach ready function to it.

Here are few commands I have given in chrome console to explain it more.

```
typeof document
"object"

$(document).ready
function (a){e.bindReady(),A.add(a);return this}

document.ready
undefined
```

Here document.ready showing undefined is making clear that it is not known to dom and $(document).ready showing its definition with the help of jquery